# Window function in Join subquery missing rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my query, I am using 2 different window functions to pull the last activity for all my items. I decided to use a subquery in the join because if I put both window functions in a single select my run time takes forever or doesn't even finish.

```
`SELECT --*
            
-- Remove Ranks from result screen
            X.ProductID,
            X.ProductDescription,
            X.ProductStatusDescription,
            X.SalesOrderID,
            X.[SO Ship Date],
            X.SalesQty,
            X.[SO Branch],
            X.PurchaseOrderID,
            X.[PO Ship Date],
            X.PurchaseQty,
            X.[PO Branch]

FROM(
SELECT P.ProductID,
       P.ProductDescription,
       P.ProductStatusDescription,
       SO.FullSalesOrderID SalesOrderID,
       SO.ShipDate 'SO Ship Date',
       SOL.StockQuantity_LowestUM SalesQty,
       SO.ShipBranchID 'SO Branch',
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.ProductID ORDER BY SO.OrderDate DESC, SO.ShipDate DESC) AS SalesRank,-- I know it is row number not a real rank, rank creates duplicates if order and ship are the same dates
       PT.FullPurchaseOrderID PurchaseOrderID,
       PT.ReceiveBranchID 'PO Branch',
       PT.ShipDate 'PO Ship Date',
       PT.StockQuantity_LowestUM PurchaseQty

  FROM UV_Products AS P WITH (NOLOCK) LEFT JOIN 
                        (Select POL.ProductID PID,
                        PO.FullPurchaseOrderID,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY POL.ProductID ORDER BY PO.OrderDate DESC, PO.ShipDate DESC) AS PurchaseRank, 
                        PO.ReceiveBranchID,
                        PO.ShipDate,
                        POL.StockQuantity_LowestUM
                FROM UV_PurchaseOrderLines POL LEFT JOIN 
                UV_PurchaseOrders PO WITH (NOLOCK) ON PO.FullPurchaseOrderID = POL.FullPurchaseOrderID
                WHERE PO.OrderStatus <> 'X' 
                ) AS PT ON PT.PID = P.ProductID 
   FULL OUTER JOIN 
   UV_SalesOrderLines AS SOL WITH (NOLOCK) on SOL.ProductID = P.ProductID  LEFT JOIN 
   UV_SalesOrders AS SO WITH (NOLOCK) ON SOL.FullSalesOrderID = SO.FullSalesOrderID 
 
                
  WHERE
        P.ProductStatus IN ('1', '2')
        AND SO.OrderStatus <> 'X'
        AND PT.PurchaseRank = 1
        ) X
                        WHERE X.SalesRank = 1
            --AND X.ProductID = 87060`
```

If I uncomment the last Where clause to find item 87060 the query returns no rows. However, If I go into the individual tables I can find that item in each one. Thus, I know my query is not returning some rows. Is this due to the way I joined my subqueries or the window functions?

Comment: Do you really need all those `NOLOCK` hints?

Comment: That Full Outer Join is suspicious.   Could it be that your SalesOrderLines product id is in a different format than the one in UV_Format?  That would return a whole lot of null Product data.

Comment: It is in the same format it used to be a left join then I changed it to try and see if that would fix my problem. It didn't.

Comment: I don't think the NOLOCK hints are necessary that's just how we are told to do things here.

Comment: NOLOCK gives potentially unconsistant rows... Some rows are ignored, some other can be read twice or more... Asking for a trouble of  missing rows with all those NOLOCK tags is like trying to swim in a bucket....

Comment: "If I go into the individual tables I can find that item in each one." When querying the individual tables, did you take into account the filters on the second highest nesting level in your query? `P.ProductStatus IN ('1', '2') AND SO.OrderStatus <> 'X' AND PT.PurchaseRank = 1`. Try without those filters, just to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Removing NOLOCK didn't change anything. It was the nested filters. Thank you so much.